# Bootstrap 4 make same buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to make left buttons and right same, for now i made it with custom css but they different in PC and mobile device, here is how it looks now.

[How buttons looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4kIs.jpg)

```
            <h3>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="one">SHORT</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="two">SHORT</a>
            </h3>
            <h3>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="three">FEW WORDS</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="four">SHORT</a>
            </h3>
```

[CSS looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMAIK.jpg)

Comment: if you want to keep same width then probably you should add some width in pixels.

Comment: Please explain what is exactly you want? The length of left side to be as at right side even if enlarged?

Comment: @IStepashka left top and bottom buttons need to be equal and right top and bottom buttons should be equal. Left side buttons should be longer than right

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is all about flexbox, then you could use Bootstrap grid for this task or style just buttons using flexbox without the need of using grid.

The main challange here is just to prefix all properties to make resulting css cross browser. I wouldn't use table layout, because it is not a flexible solution and with flexbox you have a lot more control over button's appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you put them into table ,giving width of 100%.

something like that:

css:

td a {width:100%}

```
 <table>
    <tr><td> 
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="one">SHORT</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="two">SHORT</a>

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td> <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="three">FEW WORDS</a>  </td>
            <td>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="four">SHORT</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: okay, but now text inside buttons not centered https://imgur.com/svlLPuF

Comment: try placing style of padding-left:0px to those

Comment: yeah, that's helped